# How to speed up Google Apps Script runtime?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am a beginner in the programming world, I created a script to go through [table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hvKn.png) and bring the values ​​as they are in [table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hvKn.png) according to the periods informed in it.

The script works correctly because it is very slow at run time. I would like some help to try and make him faster.

I searched for arrays but I could not understand what I could do to apply this function.

link spreadsheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mXPCEC50rw49GU42wM-VoQjVFqeGpw7O7A_eo5tZMms/edit#gid=1483928389

link Script : https://script.google.com/d/MRZzi4FhForjALEjRtYg7-CuYWxd3EZHO/edit?mid=ACjPJvFf4IPyfgW5E8N_XRpLXHxjNzQMt2gpkcMd0L7nom15r8yLAaUfGyxmhInUC2B9cVfhDFNmRVqycy7hfyOjIv3IcxkEPxOWx8aSfeGF6zjklcEyKc-daU6m3hDBVTEDq_HpC-gowQI&uiv=2

```js
function teste() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Página6");
  var tabela = ss.getRange(3, 9, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  for(var l1 = 3 ; l1 <= tabela.length ; l1 ++ ){
    var tab1 = ss.getRange(l1,8).getValue();
    for( var l2 = 3 ; l2 <= tabela.length ; l2 ++ ){
      var tab2 = ss.getRange(l2,12).getValue();

      if (tab1 == tab2){

        for( var col = 13 ; col < 17 ; col ++){
             var coluna = ss.getRange(2, col).getValue();

          if( ss.getRange(l1, 9).getValue() == ss.getRange(2, col).getValue()){
               ss.getRange(l2, col).setValue(ss.getRange(l1, 10).getValue());
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Could you include a copy of your sheet (with any personal data removed) so that we can see what this script is doing?

Comment: follow the spreadsheet link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mXPCEC50rw49GU42wM-VoQjVFqeGpw7O7A_eo5tZMms/edit#gid=1483928389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to convert the table as the following image. You want to convert the left table to the right table.

[image]

- Each number of `Produto` from `Mês 1` to `Mês 4` is the same.
- The number of `Mês` is sorted.
- The place of left and right tables is fixed in your sample.

  - Left table is `H2:J38`.
  - Right table is `L2:P11`.
- You want to speed up of your script by modifying.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the important point is that the values for putting to the sheet are prepared, and then the prepared values are put to the sheet using `setValues()`.
- In this modification, also, the values retrieved by `getValues()` are prepared and put to the sheet using `setValues()`.

#### Modified script:

```
function teste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Página6");
  var values = ss.getRange(3, 8, ss.getLastRow() - 2, 5).getValues();

  // Value are parsed and put them to an object.
  var obj = values.reduce(function(o, e) {
    if (o[e[0]]) {
      o[e[0]][e[1]] = e[2];
    } else {
      o[e[0]] = {};
      o[e[0]][e[1]] = e[2];
    }
    return o;
  }, {});

  // Create an array for putting values to sheet.
  var ar = values.filter(function(e) {return e[4]}).map(function(e) {return Object.keys(obj[e[4]]).map(function(f) {return obj[e[4]][f]})});

  // Put the values.
  ss.getRange(3, 13, ar.length, ar[0].length).setValues(ar);
}
```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: just perfect, thank you so much, this will help me a lot. besides being able to understand how to work with arrays

Comment: @Fragosojp Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Read this, it should help you depending on the complexity of your project.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices